# ASP.NET Core: localization and language based URL-s

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-localization

I'm sorry for this question if it's dump.
I'm newbie in Asp.net core.
I'm using this tutorial: http://gunnarpeipman.com/2017/03/aspnet-core-simple-localization/#comment-140296
to do localization and globalization.
After I'm done at all, I run the application and get error: No service for type "MySolution.Localization.CustomLocalizer' has been registered".
I tried to google already but could not resolve the problem.

Please help me, I'm really appreciate it.

Comment: If you want to inject a service, you need to register it in your `Startup` class.

Comment: I did figure out this. Can you help me how to register the service in the class?

Comment: Please change the subject wording into a question, so that others know what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your custom service in `ConfigureServices()` in your `Startup` class, using `AddSingleton()` or similar methods (depending on the service's lifetime).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
  services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

  // Add application services.
  services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
  services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}
```

Here is an example, simply pass in your interface and concrete class to the configure services method in the startup.cs.